# Recycler View Not align Correctly with Tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am a fresher in android development,I applied tab layout with view pager,In Fragment i applied the Recycler view but an output Recyclerview Displaying Wrongly,Here i attached [my recyclerview display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4Qa.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/xvehiclelistRV"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

My Mainactivity.xml

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/custom_actionbar" />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_actionbar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DCEBFF"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#696969"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: you have set  your viewpager height to `match_parent` so it is taking all the space inside the main container. if you are using relative layout as the parent layout then add the `layout_below` tag for viewpager to be under your tab layout.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , set the height of relative layout as match_parent

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/xvehiclelistRV"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  />
```

Secondly , If you want any view below of other view , always use layout_below in case of relative layout . Or else you can use linear layout , and provide the orientation wither horizontal or vertical on the basis of your requirement . This will place the view in order .

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/custom_actionbar"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DCEBFF"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#696969"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black"/>
```

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Use this blog , for better understanding on linear and relative layout . 
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-layout-relative-linear-frame

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Actvity Design :-

[image: just check out image]

Replace code with Mainactivity.xml with my code :-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFF" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```